# Asp.net core -> How to Delete Row from table with pKey(invoice_id, row_id)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm using MS SQL Server 2014, Visual Studio 2019, ASP.NET Core 5.0 with C#.

After having created two tables - **Invoice** and **Rows**

Invoice {inv_id, client, address}
Rows {inv_id, row_id, product, price}

the "Invoice table has pkey= inv_id"
the "Rows table has pkey=(inv_id,row_id)"

When I click on the delete button (on Index) it **asks for two parameters** but, **asp-route-id** permits only one id.

The Delete button is :

```
a asp-page="./Delete" asp-route-id="@item.row_id" class="btn"
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: We cannot help without seeing your code and/or how your handling data access,

Comment: It seem i cant post all the code here so I'm posting a mega.io link : <br> https://mega.nz/folder/kQtSFRyI#BLhS5fulLEY52XKMU6zNvg         In it are included : the Index page, index.schtml.sc and the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`asp-route-[parameter]` can multiple parameters. For example:

```
<a asp-page="./Delete" asp-route-rowid="@item.row_id" asp-route-invid="@item.inv_id" class="btn">
```

Take the rowid and invid as the parameter in the bakend.

```
public ActionResult Delete(int invId, int rowId)()
{

}
```

[Here is the official introduction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-5.0#asp-route-value).

Answer (score -1):

**Thank you very much to both.**
I had to combine both of the answers to make it work.

**This is the solution that worked for me : (lets hope it helps someone else too)**


**Index.cshtml ==>**

a asp-page="./Delete" asp-route-invid="@item.invId" asp-route-rowid="@item.rowId" class="btn btn-danger"


**Index.cshtml.cs ==>**
(Unchanged)


**Delete.cshtml ==>**
(Unchanged)


**Delete.cshtml.cs ==>**

```
    [BindProperty]
    public InvoiceRows InvoiceRows { get; set; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? invid, int rowid)
    {
        if (invid < 0)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        InvoiceRows= await _context.InvoiceRows.Where(r => r.rowid== rowid)
            FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.invid== invid);

        if (InvoiceRows== null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Page();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(int invid, int rowid)
    {
        if (invid< 0 || rowid< 0)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        InvoiceRows= await _context.InvoiceRows.FindAsync(invid, rowid);

        if (InvoiceRows!= null)
        {
            _context.InvoiceRows.Remove(InvoiceRows);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
```

**RowsController.cs ==>**

(Delete controller)

```
    [Route("~/Rows/delete/{invId}/{rowId}")]
    **public async Task<ActionResult> Delete**(int invId, int rowId)
    {
        if (invId< 0 || rowId< 0)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var InvoiceRows= await _context.InvoiceRows.Where(r => r.rowId== rowId)
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.invId== invId);
        if (InvoiceRows == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return View(InvoiceRows);
    }
```